# Split elements before the first number

Tags: python, xpath, split, scrapy

I have this text appearing after using xpath :

```
',\n                             31.05.2017,\n        20h10\n'
```

I have been able to get this by using split(',')[1]:

```
'\n                             31.05.2017'
```

However what I want is to only have the date. The thing is the date changes all the time depending on the page I am scraping. So what I need is just to get rid of the /n and the spaces that are before the first number that appears.

If you could help it would be amazing thank you :)

Comment: Can you share `HTML` sample for the same? I saw that you've already accept the solution, but there might be `XPath` solution, so you don't need to handle output with `split()` or `strip()`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative with your original text:

```
In [893]: text = ',\n                             31.05.2017,\n        20h10\n'

In [898]: text.split(',\n')[1].strip()
Out[898]: '31.05.2017'
```

Split by `,\n` and take the first item from that split list, then call `str.strip` and remove leading whitespaces.

Comment: Congrats on breaking the 9k mark ;-) [You're close...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

Comment: @VladimirOustinov Why do in 2 lines, what you could do with 1? Anyway, no probs.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply *strip* the string to remove leading and trailing whitespaces; the new line character `'\n'` is also whitespace:

```
>>> '\n                             31.05.2017'.strip()
'31.05.2017'
```